# Three different `this` behaviours for three different JS engines

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, deno

I was learning about the `this` keyword and how it means different things with regards to regular functions vs ES6 arrow functions and function expressions and I came across something odd when trying to run the following code in Chrome, Deno and Node. So I prepared following:

**Example**:

```
function foo(n) {
    console.log("***Begin Foo****")
    console.log(`n = ${n}\nthis = ${this}\nthis.count = ${this.count}`)
    console.log("****End Foo****")
    this.count++;
}

var count = 1;
for (let i = 0; i < 5 ; ++i) {
    foo(i)
}

console.log("From global this.count = "+this.count)
console.log(this)
```

**Deno** output:

```
PS E:\webdev\js_scratchspace> deno run .\another_this.js
***Begin Foo****
error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined   
    console.log(`n = ${n}\nthis = ${this}\nthis.count = ${this.count}`)
                                                               ^       
    at foo (file:///E:/webdev/js_scratchspace/another_this.js:24:64)   
    at file:///E:/webdev/js_scratchspace/another_this.js:31:5
```

**Node** output:

```
PS E:\webdev\js_scratchspace> node .\another_this.js
***Begin Foo****
n = 0
this = [object global]
this.count = undefined
****End Foo****       
***Begin Foo****      
n = 1
this = [object global]
this.count = NaN      
****End Foo****       
***Begin Foo****      
n = 2
this = [object global]
this.count = NaN      
****End Foo****       
***Begin Foo****
n = 3
this = [object global]
this.count = NaN
****End Foo****
***Begin Foo****
n = 4
this = [object global]
this.count = NaN
****End Foo****
From global this.count = undefined
{}
```

**Chrome** output:

```
***Begin Foo****
n = 0
this = [object Window]
this.count = 1
****End Foo****
***Begin Foo****
n = 1
this = [object Window]
this.count = 2
****End Foo****
***Begin Foo****
n = 2
this = [object Window]
this.count = 3
****End Foo****
***Begin Foo****
n = 3
this = [object Window]
this.count = 4
****End Foo****
***Begin Foo****
n = 4
this = [object Window]
this.count = 5
****End Foo****
From global this.count = 6
Window {window: Window, self: Window, document: document, name: '', location: Location, …}
```

According to my understanding of this, where for arrow functions `this` has no explicit binding and refers to the scope's `this` in which the arrow function was defined, whereas for regular functions `this` refers to the context from which it was invoked, Chrome's output seems to make the most sense to me. I don't understand why for example, Node would not recognize the global object as `this`. I am least bothered by Deno's output as I guess I may not understand what it's trying to do exactly.

Can someone explain why Node, Deno and Chrome are giving me different outputs?

Comment: Did you have a question or was this just an observation?

Comment: Maybe Deno defaults to strict mode?

Comment: @Jamiec that's a good question. This was an observation primarily, but I was hoping for some clarification on why Node and Deno are giving me these different outputs. As I phrased in my question, I am befuddled by Node giving me `this = {}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Three different `this` behaviours for three different JS engines

That's a misleading way of putting it. You have three different JS environments, but they're all using the same engine.

> I am befuddled by Node giving me `this = {}`.

That's not what it's giving you: `this = [object global]`.

What you're not seeing in Node is `var count` showing up as `this.count`. One way you'd get that behavior (I don't know whether that's what Node is doing) is by wrapping the entire code in an IIFE. If you do:

```js
(function() {
  /* YOUR CODE HERE... */
})();
```

in Chrome, you'll see the same behavior, because then `var count` is just a function-local variable.

And as @Barmar said, you'd get Deno's behavior by [defaulting to strict mode](https://deno.land/manual@v1.14.1/typescript/overview#strict-by-default) (in addition to wrapping the code in an IIFE).

Conclusion: Relying on `this` in the global scope is not a great idea. Try to use `this` only for methods that will be called on objects (such as if you have `foo.bar()` anywhere, then the body of `bar() {...}` may use `this` to refer to `foo`).